# Sort while neglecting regex pattern

Tags: linux, sort, gnu

I want to sort a list of url (1 url/line) in a file, such that if the url begins with `www.` or `m.`, the sort is done assuming that, that part doesn't exists (or is irrelevant for sorting). Any suggestions?

## Example

```
facebook.com###page
fahrrad.de###userlike-popup
m.facebook.com##.cx
www.facebook.com##body
www.fahrrad.de###userlike-footerbar
```

The sorted file looks like this

```
www.facebook.com##body
m.facebook.com##.cx
facebook.com###page
www.fahrrad.de###userlike-footerbar
fahrrad.de###userlike-popup
```

## Explanation

- `facebook.com` precedes `fahrrad.de` as c comes before h
- `www.facebook.com##body` precedes `m.facebook.com##.cx` as `b` comes before `.`
- `m.facebook.com##.cx` precedes `facebook.com###page` as `.` comes before `#`
- `www.fahrrad.de###userlike-footerbar` precedes `fahrrad.de###userlike-popup` as f comes before p

Comment: Could you post an example of the unsorted file?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I have included the sorted file example, you can unsort it in any way you like

Comment: I suggested this because it's easier to potential answerers to just copy/paste than spend time unsorting, I know it's just a couple of seconds, but it could make a more appealing question, and is part of the standard way of a good question: a testable exampĺe and the expected output.

Comment: as per https://ascii.cl/, `#` is `0x23` and `.`  is `0x2E`... so it should be `#` comes before `.` but when I do `printf '.\nb\n#\n' | sort` I get `.` before `#` ... interestingly, `printf '.\nb\n#\n' | perl -e 'print sort <>'` gives `#` before `.` can anyone explain this?

Comment: @Sundeep I get `# . b` with that `printf | sort`. I don't understand where the order OP specified comes from. Using `LC_ALL=C` should give the correct ASCII order.

Comment: @Sundeep I doubt it. Try `printf '.\nb\n#\n' | LC_ALL=C sort`.

Comment: yeah, that gives me same result as `perl` one.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always add a character after the part you want to skip and sort from there on (and remove that character afterwards):

If your `sed` supports the `-E` option (recent versions of GNU `sed` do and older versions would take `-r` instead, though that's less portable to non-GNU implementations):

```
<file sed -E 's/^(www\.|m\.)?/&:/' | sort -t: -k2 | sed 's/://'
```

Portably, you can do the same with `awk` or `perl`:

```
<file awk '{sub(/^(www\.|m\.)?/, "&:"); print}' | sort -t: -k2 | sed 's/://'
```

```
<file perl -pe 's/^(www\.|m\.)?/$&:/' | sort -t: -k2 | sed 's/://'
```

Though with POSIX `sed`, you could always do:

```
<file sed -e 's/^www\./&:/;t' -e 's/^m\./&:/;t' -e 's/^/:/' |
  sort -t: -k2 | sed 's/://'
```

Or you could add a `.` to the start of lines that don't start with `www.` nor `m.` and sort on the part the follows the first `.`:

```
<file sed -e '/^www\./b' -e '/^m\./!s/^/./' | sort -t. -k2 | sed 's/^\.//'
```

Comment: How is `<file sed -E 's/^(www\.|m\.)?/&:/'` different from `sed -E 's/^(www\.|m\.)?/&:/' file`?

Comment: @Nikhil, see for instance: [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/70756)

Answer (score 4):

With `perl` alone:

```
perl -e 'print sort {$a=~s/^(www|m)\.//r cmp $b=~s/^(www|m)\.//r} <>'
```

`$a` and `$b` are special variables in Perl to allow specifying custom `sort` comparisons

`s/^(www|m)\.//r` will remove the leading `www.` or `m.` portions from input lines before applying `sort`

`<>` in this context will give array of input lines

[Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) variant:

```
perl -e 'print map { $_->[0] }
         sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] or $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
         map { [$_, s/^(www|m)\.//r] } <>'
```

Similarly, with `ruby`:

```
# can golf it to {_1.sub(/^(www|m)\./, "")} on latest version
ruby -e 'puts readlines.sort_by {|s| s.sub(/^(www|m)\./, "")}'
```

Comment: In the `perl` variant at least, you end up doing the stripping of those prefixes for each comparison. You may want to add a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) step.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see this:

```
sed 's;^\([wm\.]*\)\(.*\)$;\2 \1\2;' file | sort | awk '{ print $2 }'
```